# Avoiding key conflict in riak?

Tags: riak

Sorry if this question sounds stupid. I understand that Riak is eventual-consistent and not atomic, so conflicts need to be handled somehow, either by Riak or by the application. However, I can't seem to figure out how to avoid key conflicts.

For example, say I have an object with key `apple` in Riak. How to prevent any *creation* of new objects with that key to succeed? There seems to only have `update` operation, but not `create`. What happens if I create a brand new object with the `apple` key and write that to Riak - will that simply overwrite the existing copy? That sounds very scary.

Also what happens when two concurrent *creations* happen for the same key? That is, two completely irrelevant objects are written to riak, both wanting to have the `apple` key. Will one of them fail, and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How you write (or do not) to the same key depends on your application's logic. You may want to update existing records, in which case writing to the same key makes perfect sense. If you want to make sure that no two records are written to the same key by mistake, try setting IF_NONE_MATCH in your store request (or whatever it's called in your version of Riak client).

If concurrent writes to the same key are possible in your application, you should use casual context and implement conflict resolution either on the client, or on the server side http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/conflict-resolution/

Comment: Hmm I don't think `if_none_match` should be set: The if_not_modified, if_none_match, and asis parameters are set only for messages sent between nodes in a Riak cluster and should not be set by Riak clients.

Comment: For causal context, conflict resolution happens on the read side - I want the write to fail.

Comment: You can't completely avoid writing to the same key to my understanding. Think of a cluster suffering from a network partition, when one node may not know about writes to another node. `if_none_match` is exposed in the official Riak client for Java, and I know for sure it causes a store operation to fail if the key already exists.